# WHILE LOOP You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, while-loop, declare

Here is my Database server information

Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10

I run below code and got a error messate

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5;

  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END;

I got an error messate: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3
```

Comment: The rules for writing stored programs can be found https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the deliminator temporary because in procedure deliminator semicolon **;** is used for statement end. if we did not change deliminator SQL consider procedure is ended in between and it does not compile successfully.

so before start the procedure change deliminator **$$** and end of procedure revert the original deliminator **;**

Try below code using Mysql Command line

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dowhile$$
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5;
WHILE v1 > 0 DO
SET v1 = v1 - 1;
END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

After that you call procedure using

```
call dowhile();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()

BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5;

  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

You need to temporarily change the delimiter, so that MySQL can accept a sequence of statements, rather than stop after the first semi-colon.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 11

Comment: What querying tool are you using?  I ran this on DataGrip and it works absolutely fine.  After the SET, I even added SELECT v1; so that I could verify the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5;

  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: No. can not  ```There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 11
STR: //
SQL: DELIMITER //```

Comment: It was correct code (I checked it before posting). Other answers were the same (with different delimiter). So probably something was with your client.